# switch network on and off of a virtual remote server

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip, interface

I need to perform a testing panel which disconnects a network cable and connect it again on a specific virtual server via a php web page.

I found that [ip & ifconfig](http://www.tty1.net/blog/2010-04-21-ifconfig-ip-comparison_en.html) can disconnect a network, but I can't turn it back on,
because I'm doing these operations via php with ssh like this:

```
exec('ssh -p 22 root@192.168.0.101 "ip link set dev eth0 down"',$output); //work
exec('ssh -p 22 root@192.168.0.101 "ip link set dev eth0 up"',$output); // doesn't work
```

I'm using virtual servers 'CentOS' on virtual box,
is there an alternative way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can script Virtualbox using `modifyvm --cableconnected<1-N> on|off` (http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp20394080).